# How to get notifications on database column changes

Tags: database, node.js, watch, mysql

i am using mysql-client library for mysql on node.js server.
I am looking for library in node.js sever that run continously and watch on mysql table column and send notifications when changes occour in table column;

Can anyone please name some libray that i am looking for.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "changes in table column"?  New values appearing?  New columns?  Changes to the structure?

Comment: i have a column name 'amount' whenever amount becomes 10 dollars or below 10 dollars, notification send to client

Comment: This is the wrong approach. That logic should be built into your application so that when it modifies the value, it checks the new value against whatever rules you have. The database is there to store information, not act upon it

Answer (score 0):

use the sql Service Broker.
basically you subscribe to a query, so when your table is updated the server sends a notification of a change to you.

Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach) great article

edit: Nevermind, didn't read the question thoroughly enough. sorry! - leaving my answer to anyone else that reads it wrong and thinks its c# :)